# How to user a .CSV column in WHERE CONDITION

Tags: soql, integration, query, informatica

Is there any free tool like Informatica cloud or something where I can put a ID column of CSV file in WHERE Condition.

Scenario.
I have csv file having ID of 10k Accounts. Now, I have to query the opportunities related to them. Is there any way where I can write a query for those accounts.

Select Id,NAME,(select Id from Opportunities) from Account where ID IN (ID COLUMN OF CSV). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Immediate thoughts are - 
A) Maybe use a join report? 
Not sure of the criteria that you used to generate the 10k account ids, but if you can user report filters to refine a list of account records, you may be able to join opportunities on the basis of common account id.

B) 
If this is a recurring process, then maybe the ids can be loaded into an sobject, and then run some batched logic across the table to batch the id's into sets of say 1000 accounts, and then retrieve the associated opptys.

C) didnt the old Excel Connector allow this sort of thing?  You'd stick the account id's into a column, then the connector would chug through the list and perform an outer join of sorts for you. See [Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/excel-connector/wiki/JoinTables) for more info.

Just a few ideas. Good luck!

Cheers,
CH

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Excel Connector. I still use it every day, but I forgot that it can do table joins.